# adding a table with hook_schema()

Tags: drupal

I plan to add a table with the help of hook_schema. I have defined the schema and am calling it in my module . However, no schema is getting created. Where am i going wrong. I have the following code in my sample2.install file

```
    function sample2_schema(){
    $schema['mytable1'] = array(
    'description' => t('My table description'),
    'fields' => array(
     'mycolumn1' => array(
      'description' => t('My unique identifier'),
      'type' => 'serial',
      'unsigned' => true,
      'not null' => true,
      ), 
     'myvarchar' => array(
       'description' => t('My varchar'),
       'type' => 'varchar',
       'length' => 32,
       'not null' => true,
      ),
      'mytimestamp' => array(
        'description' => t('My timestamp'),
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => true,
      ),
    ),
    'indexes' => array(
      'myvarchar' => array('myvarchar'),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('mycolumn1'),
    'unique keys' => array(
       'mycolumn1' => array('mycolumn1'),
    ),
    );

    return $schema;
    }
      function sample2_install(){
    drupal_install_schema('sample2');
       }
      function sample2_uninstall(){
    drupal_uninstall_schema('sample2');
        }
```

To invoke it, i am using the following code in my sample2.module file.

```
        $record = (object) NULL;
    $record->myvarchar = 'blah';
    $record->mytimestamp = strtotime('now');
    drupal_write_record('mytable1',$record);
```

This does not create any table .

Comment: Have you tried disabling/re-enabling the module from the admin page? `hook_install` should only run when the module is first enabled (please correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Yes, i have enabled them many times and cleared cache. It does not create any table of the name 'mytable1'

Comment: Which version of Drupal are you using? If you're using 7.x, it may be because you shouldn't explicictly be calling `drupal_install_schema` and `drupal_uninstall_schema` -- http://drupal.org/node/970598 However, it still seems that your table should show up in the database...

Comment: I am using drupal 6. I think there is something wrong in my invocation code                  $record = (object) NULL;
    $record->myvarchar = 'blah';
    $record->mytimestamp = strtotime('now');
    drupal_write_record('mytable1',$record);      I am including it in the sample2.module file.

Answer (score 6):

If the sample2 module existed and was enabled before the addition of the `sample2_schema()` and `sample2_install()` functions, you need to uninstall it (not just disabling), then install/enable it again. Otherwise, Drupal wont use your `hook_install()`. Another solution is to install the schema in a `hook_update_N()` implementation. Then use u`pdate.php` or `drush updatedb` to run the update code.

```
function sample2_update_6001() {
  drupal_install_schema('sample2');
}
```

Comment: There's a related interesting topic: [Updating tables: don't use hook_schema() (https://drupal.org/node/150220)](https://drupal.org/node/150220), http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45671/must-new-tables-be-created-in-hook-update-n/45677#45677

Answer (score 1):

To add a new table to an existing module db schema, you can do this:

```php
 /**
 * Add generic API transaction log table.
 */
function commerce_paydollar_update_7004(&$sandbox){
  // Get schema definition for this module
  $schema = commerce_paydollar_schema();
  // Create a selected table from the schema definition  
  db_create_table('commerce_paydollar_api_txn', $schema['commerce_paydollar_api_txn']);
  $sandbox['#finished'] = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: This is not correct, you must not rely on your own hook_schema() implementation in update hook implementations. If you later on add an additional column to that table, this will fall apart.

Comment: @berdir Your comment doesn't make sense. Can you actually explain on how adding an additional column to hook_schema would affect this update hook? Also, please note, this is how tables are added in the D7 Views module ( http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--views--views.install/function/views_update_6000/7 )

Comment: It affects it because then update 7004 will add the new table which already contains the additional column (because it has been defined in hook_schema() and update 7005 will try to add it *again*. Views does *not* to this, it does use versioned hook_schema_implementations, as you can see in your link (it calls views_schema_6000()). See http://drupal.org/node/150220

Comment: @berdir Thanks for the reply. I still can't see why update_7005 would need to add the field, or table, again? This is a db_create_table call. Once the table is created, it is created. Nevertheless, a more verbose example should include if (!db_table_exists('commerce_paydollar_api_txn') ){} prior to creating the table. Which is what in fact the above module does, and is working fine.

Comment: My link above contains a detailed example. Consider this: 1. You add a new table in update 7004. then you need to add a *new* column to that table and create update 7005 for that and also update hook_schema() to include the additional column. Now someone using an old version upgrades and first runs 7004, which creates the table *including* the new column because it is defined in yourmodule_schema(). Then update 7005 tries to add that column as well. Kaboom. Sure, you could add ad db_field_exists() here but this will get more and more complex, for example if you start changing columns.

Comment: This is the best solution ! If you uninstall the schemas using the other answers then you will loose you existing data

Answer (score 0):

See another question that is very similar, [Drupal 6 module install file not creating tables in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496529/drupal-6-module-install-file-not-creating-tables-in-database).

In the second part of your question, you talk about 'invoking' the table.  Before trying to write anything to the table from a module, I would suggest connecting to your database and checking if the table has been created successfully first.

Uninstalling/reinstalling your module will invoke the schema creation within the install file.  If the syntax is correct, your table will get created.

If you find that your table is not getting created and you believe it is a syntax issue, I would suggest simplifying your code by first trying to add just one column, then the rest of the columns, and last the indexes.  You can install/uninstall between each of those steps.